# Tags: "point of view" and "grammatical person"

Tags: discussion, tags

ctype.h recently created a tag called [point-of-view](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-of-view).  So far, this tag exists on [only one question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/tenses-from-a-point-of-view), and I think the tag itself is fine.

However, I disagree with the tag wiki description ctype.h proposed:

> For questions about determining the point of view of a given construction, i.e. first-, second-, or third-person.

In my view, this is conflating *point of view* with *grammatical person*.  These two concepts are closely related, but differ somewhat in the details:

- *Point of view* is chiefly concerned with narratives and works of fiction; it includes not only first-, second-, and third-person, but also descriptors such as *omniscient*, *close*, and *alternating*.
- *Grammatical person* is more general and does not include these descriptors.

Since we often talk about first-/second-/third-person from a grammatical perspective without talking about the point of view of a story, I think we should come up with another solution--perhaps two tags, or perhaps a different description in the tag wiki.

Comment: +1 Moreover, the one question tagged with POV addresses *temporal* perspective, not *personal*; and that to my mind is adequately addressed under the category *tense*. I'd vote to kill the tag.

Comment: What do you think the tag wiki should say?

Comment: @StoneyB Perhaps post this as an answer, as to gauge community support?

Comment: @WendiKidd As you wish.

Answer (score 1):

1. As OP says, *point of view* is a critical term belonging to the study of narrative, film and art, not a linguistic one. These are, I believe, matters which we intend to exclude from consideration here, except insofar as they impinge on English usage.
2. Again as OP says, the linguistic dimension of first-, second- and third-person perspectives has its own term of art, *person*; and I think we should prefer our own terms to those from other disciplines.
3. Finally, the only question which at this writing has been tagged [point-of-view](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-of-view) is concerned with **temporal** perspectives, not personal. This too possesses a familiar linguistic term, *tense*; and again I think this should be preferred.

I think the tag should be explicitly deprecated.